# Resize a matrix to a double array

Tags: c++, matrix, double

I have a std matrix A such as

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > A(9,std::vector<double>9);
```

and to calculate its inverse i need to define it as a double of a size [1*81] such as

```
double newA[1*81];
```

is there a function like *resize* that I can do this conversion from a matrix to a double without a for loop??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is *not* a sensible type for a matrix in C++. If you want to keep it simple just implement your own indexing functions, but keep dense matrices in linear storage please (i.e. just one `std::vector<double>` for example). That way you also don't need to do much to convert (`v.data()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't avoid the loop.

There is a difference in memory layout between `vector<double>` and `double[]`. A `vector` is implemented as a pointer to some data, somewhere else in the memory, while a `double[9]` is directly using the space of 9 doubles.

That means the values in your `vector<vector>` are not necessarily contiguous in memory, while they are in a `double[]`, or even in a `double[][]`.